# "NoClassDefFoundError: GenericApplicationListener" when switching from Spring Boot 1.3.0M1 to 1.3.0M2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Starter created Soring Boot application I switched from Spring Boot 1.3.0M1 to 1.3.0M2. When trying to start the application (either from STS 3.7.0 or via spring-boot:run at the command line) I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:435)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:385)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:362)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:231)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:206)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:971)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:960)
        at com.daimler.daivb.services.application.dummyservice.DummyServiceApplication.main(DummyServiceApplication.java:18)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:378)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 25 more
```

The mentioned class has been added in spring-context version 4.2.0 but when looking at the dependency tree I can see that Spring Boot 1.3.0M2 still depends on spring-context 4.1.6:

```
[INFO] com.company.services.application:dummyservice:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.3.0.M2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.0.M2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.0.M2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
```

Comment: Trying to add the dependency to spring-context 4.2.0.RC3 explicitly, by excluding the 4.1.6 transitive dependency, leads to the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;`

Comment: Spring Boot 4.1 should use Spring 4.2 make sure you aren't specifying a `spring.version` property in your pom or have some other dependency that is forcing the 4.1.6 version.

Comment: I ran into the same thing.  I updated my spring cloud application to use the spring boot 1.3.0.M5 version and it seems to have tons of dependencies on spring framework 4.1.6.  In the dependency tree I note some are 4.2.1 but most are still 4.1.6.  I don't have an explicit 4.1.6 spring.version anywhere

Comment: I solved this by running the build with -U for updating all the snapshot dependencies.

Comment: I had a similar problem and changing my spring version from 4.1.6 to 4.2.1 in my build.gradle solved it.

Answer (score 20):

Spring Boot manages a bunch of dependencies for you and [allows you to add them without specifying the version](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-dependency-management). Spring Boot is obviously based on Spring Framework and uses the latest and greatest so you should avoid at all cost to fix the spring framework version to use yourself.

If you have upgraded to a newer version (to include a bug fix or something) make sure to *remove the override* before you upgrade Spring Boot as the new version it requires may be incompatible with your override.

If you are using other projects that *also* provide a dependency management on Spring Framework (such as Spring Cloud) make sure that the dependency management of Spring Boot takes precedence. With Maven, make sure to add the `spring-boot-dependencies` BOM as [the *first entry* in the `<dependenciesManagement>` section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent).

Comment: I would opt in for this answer too. My pom.xml had two different dependencies declaration for spring-test-mvc and spring-test which apparently caused the class loading to mess up. Removing spring-test-mvc resolved the issue for me.

Comment: The last time I had this problem, an update from Spring-Boot version `1.3.7` to `1.3.8` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem because my POM had a properties section with a  `<spring.version>` tag copied from another project.

Remove any `<abc.version>` tag in your properties section that may conflict with Spring Boot libraries.

Answer (score 6):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
```

From the above error, application is unable to find the class defined from the jar dependencies. `GenericApplicationListener` is added from spring version 4.2.

Upgrade your Spring version to 4.2 and recheck.