# Spring boot and spring cloud config client error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm trying to configure and run a spring boot app with spring cloud config client. I have successfully run the config server but the client is giving error while loading the application context.

While searching , I got pointers towards version/dependency conflict etc and have tried using different versions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Error snippet:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Following is the sample pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>lab-3-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>lab-3-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.example.Lab3ClientApplication</start-class>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Angel.SR4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: [noclassdeffounderror-genericapplicationlistener-when-switching-from-spring-boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489947/noclassdeffounderror-genericapplicationlistener-when-switching-from-spring-bo) is worth reading.

Comment: @asgs Thanks but I have already read and tried those options. I tried specifying the spring.version to be 4.2.1 ; tried to do mvn -U clean install ; tried to specify lower version of  cloud-starter-config explicitly & also tried to change the order of my dependencies etc. But no luck yet :-(

Comment: ok, the class mentioned as missing is from `spring-context` artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angel release train builds on **Spring Boot 1.2.x**, and is **incompatible** in some areas with Spring Boot 1.3.x. So, i would change the version of spring boot to `1.2.7.RELEASE`:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I used version 1.2.7.RELEASE it is getting loaded and running. However, it seems not be working with the cloud config server i.e. not retrieving the config from the server already running. Server was running with latest spring boot. Will keep updating if anything changes...

Comment: By default, spring cloud config client looks for a config server that runs on port `8888` of `localhost`.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be some other problem. The /metrics api is returning a status=404 . The same is working fine with config server and if I invoke the config server api with client id , it is returning correct config value.

Comment: I'm running the config server at 8001 but have specified the following in bootstrap.properties of client: spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8001        .... Though it seems to be some other issue as the  /metrics returning 404

Comment: See here https://github.com/alimate/distributed-conf-server-client maybe it helps

Comment: Otherwise, ask another question about config client/server relationship. This one was about your version conflict which is solved i guess

Comment: `/metrics` need `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency. did you add it?

Comment: Thank you Ali! /metrics is still having some issues but my code controller mapping is working. I would really be interested if there is any way to run this with 1.3.x version of spring boot....  Thanks for your help again

Comment: [Read this from josh long](https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-spring-cloud-apps-from-spring-boot-12-to)

Comment: Should the spring boot cloud config client be always a Rest client?. I have a Jms spring boot config client. The properties values are null when it fetches from spring cloud config server. It works for Rest client. I do not have spring-web dependency for jms client.

Answer (score -1):

try to add the following to your `<dependencyManagement> <dependencies>`:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Angel.SR4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```