# Run spring boot application error: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a spring project and try to make it use spring boot and to run at embadded tomcat following :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

This is my Application

```
//@Configuration
//@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "gux.prome")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

If I use maven command: `mvn spring-boot:run`, the project starts fine, but I need to debug , so I run this main method at InteliJ, exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:414)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:394)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:263)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at gux.prome.config.Application.main(Application.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
....
```

This is the pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>gux</groupId>
  <artifactId>prome-data</artifactId>


  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>prome-data Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- guava -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end of guava -->


    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


  <properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  </properties>


  <build>

    <finalName>prome-data</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <!--<plugin>-->
      <!-- use java 7 -->
        <!--<artifactId> maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>3.1</version>-->
        <!--<configuration>-->
          <!--<source> 1.7</source>   -->
          <!--<target> 1.7</target>-->
        <!--</configuration>-->
      <!--</plugin>-->

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <!--<repositories>-->
    <!--<repository>-->
      <!--<id>spring-releases</id>-->
      <!--<url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>-->
    <!--</repository>-->
  <!--</repositories>-->

  <!--<pluginRepositories>-->
    <!--<pluginRepository>-->
      <!--<id>spring-releases</id>-->
      <!--<url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>-->
    <!--</pluginRepository>-->
  <!--</pluginRepositories>-->


</project>
```

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489947/noclassdeffounderror-genericapplicationlistener-when-switching-from-spring-bo

Answer (score 32):

This is a symptom of a version mismatch **somewhere** in your Spring dependencies, but not necessarily just Spring Boot and Spring itself. I had this between my Spring Boot parent:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

and my Spring Cloud Config dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For some reason, I am not able to define the spring-cloud-config-client dependency without an explicit version declaration.

Updating both to the latest release version (1.3.5.RELEASE and 1.1.1.RELEASE) solved it.

**Conclusion**
*Update your dependencies to the latest correct ones*

Comment: In my case, everything had same version. The only issue was, when the version was updated in pom, IDE still had cached the older version (Hint to this was same project was working for all my colleagues and not me). So when checked Module settings in IntelliJ, it showed me both the old and new versions. Had to remove the older one manually and the issue was resolved. :)

Comment: I was importing other dependencies which had springframework. I had to add             <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

Answer (score 0):

For ones using Gradle, I solved this issue setting the version of the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin in my library and in my main project to the same value:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i had the same error , i just changed the release version of the spring boot parent and now everything works right

Comment: Should be comment otherwise explain in detail.