# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface BootstrapRegistryInitialize : ConfigClientRetryBootstrapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am currently getting this exception, can someone help please.

I am using the following versions:
spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.7.0
spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap: 3.1.3
spring-cloud-dependencies: 2021.0.3

I started getting this exception when I added this maven dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Exception :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate
> interface org.springframework.boot.BootstrapRegistryInitializer :
> org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientRetryBootstrapper
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:449)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:431)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:424)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:266)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.createSpringApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:102)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:98)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createSpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:130)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
> at
> org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> ... 44 more     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class
> org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientRetryBootstrapper
> is not assignable to interface
> org.springframework.boot.BootstrapRegistryInitializer         at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.assignableCheckFailed(Assert.java:720)
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:651)
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:682)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:443)

I am upgrading to spring 2.7.0 do i need to also upgrade all the Managed Dependencies mentioned in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.7.0 in my project also ?

Comment: Please try the latest boot 2.7 and spring cloud 2021.0. See https://start.spring.io

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the problem may be a conflict of versions. I suggest you add the latest version of Spring Cloud Dependencies to the build file. For example

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.5"
    }
}
```

in my case, this solved the problem

Simular porblem :
[Run spring boot application error: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844263/run-spring-boot-application-error-cannot-instantiate-interface-org-springframew)