# Spring Boot 1.4.1 giving exception in production but not in development

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My application works fine in development but the moment I deploy it into EC2 in production I get an exception and it will not start. The POM file is:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example.app</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>app</name>
<description>My App</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add project specific below here -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the exception I get is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate
>   interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer :
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:414)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:394)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:385)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:261)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:237)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
>           at com.example.MyApplication.main(TemplatesApplication.java:16)
>           ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer.()
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
>           ... 15 more

Note: This question ["NoClassDefFoundError: GenericApplicationListener" when switching from Spring Boot 1.3.0M1 to 1.3.0M2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31489947/197127) refers to a different situation where someone DID override the versions. But I did not.

Comment: Are you deploying the same jar ?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` seeing that, one cannot think something other than a version mismatch :(

Comment: I am deploying the same war. What kind of version mismatch? I am not setting it anywhere

Comment: Did this got resolved?